# Read data from texture with any internal format on ES

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to read the data of a texture on OpenGL ES. The problem with my method is that framebuffers do not accept textures with GL_ALPHA as format. If the texture has GL_RGBA as format, everything works fine. I do not want to change the texture format to RGBA, so is there another way to read the texture data as GL_RGBA format even if the texture has the GL_ALPHA format?

I have created a texture with this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, width, height, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```

I am trying to read the data with a framebuffer with a texture attachment and glReadPixels

```
ByteBuffer pixels = memAlloc(4 * width * height); // This line is java specific, it works like a byte array
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
int fbo = glGenFramebuffers();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    // glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT after this line
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDeleteFramebuffers(fbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: the texture stores A and you want to read RGBA. what should the RGB values be? should OpenGL make up some values?

Comment: I'd just leave RGB empty just like it'd work with only A, so RGB=0

Comment: You could read the alpha and then rearrange the data how you like